# Multidimensional array Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.4

I have been stuck with this problem for quite some time now. I have this particular array with the help of laravel's Socialite.

```
"first_name" => "xxx"
"last_name" => "xx"
"email" => "xxx@gmail.com"
"work" => array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "employer" => array:2 [▼
      "id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      "name" => "FBI"
    ]
    "location" => array:2 [▶]
    "start_date" => "0000-00"
    "id" => "496298904045521"
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▶]
]
```

What I wanted to do is to get the `first_name`, `last_name`,`email` and the `name` from `work` and save it in the database after. The problem is I can't seem to retrieve the name of work but instead gives me this error message

> (1/1) ErrorException
>   Undefined index: employer

How can I make this work? Quite lost here.

Controller

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $usersocialite = Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'work'
    ])->user();

    //dd($usersocialite);
   $findUser = Fbuser::where('email',$usersocialite->email)->first();

    if ($findUser) {
        Auth::login($findUser);
        return view('home');
    }else{
        $user = new Fbuser;
        $user->first_name = $usersocialite->user['first_name'];
        $user->last_name = $usersocialite->user['last_name'];
        $user->email = $usersocialite->user['email'];
        $work=$usersocialite->user['work'];
        $w = collect([$work=>[$usersocialite->user['employer']=>[$usersocialite->user['name']]]]);
        $flattened = $w->flatten();
        $flatten->all();
        $user->work = $usersocialite->user[$flatten];
        $user->save();
        Auth::login($user);
        return view('home');
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the work name in the multidimensional array you can use something like this:

```
$user->work = $usersocialite->user['work'][0]['employer']['name'];
```

or you can use the Laravel helper function `array_get`:

```
$user->work = array_get($usersocialite->user, 'work.0.employer.name');
```

The line above will replace the code:

```
 $work=$usersocialite->user['work'];
 $w = collect([$work=>[$usersocialite->user['employer']=>[$usersocialite->user['name']]]]);
 $flattened = $w->flatten();
 $flatten->all();
 $user->work = $usersocialite->user[$flatten];
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, sir. Works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

you are accessing employer name in wrong way. you skip some indexes:

```
$w = collect([$work=>[$usersocialite->user['work'][0]['employer']=>[$usersocialite->user['work'][0]['employer']['name']]]]);
```

I can not understand what are you doing really. but I think you want something like this:

```
$w = collect(['work'=>[$work[0]['employer']=>[$work][0]['employer']['name']]]]);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Tried using this and it gives me this error 
(1/1) ErrorException
Illegal offset type

Comment: I wanted to get the name from the work array and store it in the database. Quite lost on how to get the array in another array

Comment: thanks for your patience sir but throws me again the Employer as an Undefined Index

Comment: from your suggested solution itself sir

Comment: are you sure that given array always exists?

Comment: would you please do var_dump($work) before that line? to check the array structure

Comment: When I tried Adam Finucane, it would give me an error of (1/1) ErrorException
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() so as doing a var_dump before that line.